# How to change vim ruby version

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim

I am a noob to vim and am wanting to use the `command-t` plugin, got really used to that in atom. I have done everything in the github repo but am unable to follow how to change the version of ruby that my vim is using. When I try to use the `command-t` it throws this error...

```
command-t could not load the C extension.
Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLESHOOTING in the help
VIM Ruby version 2.0.0-p648
Expected version 2.4.1-p111
for more information type:   :help command-t
```

Except like I said, I'm having a hard time following the help on the repo and there it tells me that there is no help for command-t. So my question is, what is the best way to change my vim version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

1. `$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/`
2. `$ rbenv local system`
3. `$ ruby extconf.rb`
4. `$ make clean`
5. `$ make`

Taken from [this](http://neethack.com/2014/12/command-t-dot-vim-crash-on-yosemite/) post. I've had this problem before and these steps worked for me.

Comment: Thank you!, that fixed it and allowed my to use command-t. One more question if I may. Will that interfere with using 2.4.1 ruby methods when writing code? or it that just something for command-t and vim?

Comment: I don't think it should interfere, but you can check your Ruby version with `$ ruby -v`

Comment: Ya my terminal ruby is 2.4.1. I'll jsut play it by ear and if something breaks I'll get one of the Vim gurus at my school to take a look when classes start back up next week :D Thanks again for the fix :D

Comment: I use MacVim and had a problem after upgrading to macOS Mojave where my system ruby was missing `ruby/config.h`, which caused a fatal error: `fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found`. So my system ruby seemed busted. I found that MacVim was linked against Ruby 2.3.7. I installed ruby 2.3.7 via rbenv, did `rbenv shell 2.3.7` to use that version of ruby when doing steps 3,4,5 above, and was able to build Command-T properly. Each time I upgrade macOS and/or macvim, I end up having to fight to get Command-T installed again. Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

What that error means is your vim uses a different version of ruby than command-t expects.  Rather than change the version which vim uses, what you should do is recompile command-t with vim's version of ruby.

In my case I used Homebrew to install `vim`, which will install its own ruby but without rbenv.  I also use Pathogen for plugins so I have my command-t install under `~/.vim/bundle/command-t` (with the `5-x-release` branch checked-out since i don't use neovim).

What I did was basically from [this blog post](https://souhaiebtar.github.io/how-to-compile-vim-and-install-command-t-extension/):

- find where brew's ruby is: `which vim` gave `/opt/homebrew/bin/vim` and eventually i was able to find ruby at `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`
- `cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t`
- `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb`
- `make clean`
- `make`

after that, it worked!